# Unit-test of redux-saga throws error: runSaga must be called on an iterator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, sinon, enzyme

I'm very green when it comes to coding with React and redux, and testing it with JEST, enzyme and sinon, so bear with me.

I'm trying to test the sagas in my application. Currently I'm trying to test my 'serverSaga' which is responsible for calling a REST-API and setting the state to content of the response (in this case its a food-menu).

When i try to run the test, it fails with the error:

```
runSaga must be called on an iterator

  20 | describe('Menu View Saga', () => {
  21 |   it('can retrieve todays menu', async () => {
> 22 |     await runSaga(
  23 |       {
  24 |         dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action),
  25 |         getState: () => ({})
```

Which I'm guessing has something to do with it being unable to iterate over the `yield` in `handleRequest()` from serverSaga, but I'm kinda lost as to why that is, and what I'm doing wrong.

**The test:**

```
 import sinon from "sinon";
import * as obj from "../../services/serverService";
import { handleRequest } from '../../sagas/serverSaga'
import { runSaga } from "redux-saga";
import { menuList } from '../../stubs/menuList'
import { setMenu } from '../../reducers/menuReducer'


const serverStub = sinon.stub(obj, 'callServerApi')

 serverStub.callsFake(() => {
  return {
    ...menuList.menu
  }
})

const saga = handleRequest
const dispatched = {}

describe('Menu View Saga', () => {
  it('can retrieve todays menu', async () => {
    await runSaga(
      {
        dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action),
        getState: () => ({})
      },
        saga,
        'test-url',
        'GET'
    ).done

    expect(serverStub.calledOnce).toBeTruthy()
    expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(setMenu(menuList))

  })
})
```

**serverSaga**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { put, call, take, fork, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { callServerApi } from '../services/serverService'


export function* handleRequest(url, method, data){

  //TODO - ERROR HANDLING

  return yield executeRequest(url, method, data)
}

function* executeRequest(url, method, data) {


   try { 
    let response = yield call(callServerApi, url, method, data)
    let responseSuccess = response && response.Succeeded   

    //temporary workaround - should NOT return response here,
    return response



if (responseSuccess) {

  yield success(response)
  //return response

} else {
  console.log('ERROR', response)

  //TODO - ERROR HANDLING

 }  } catch (error){
   console.log('Error from serverSaga', error)
//TODO - ERROR HANDLING
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga i realized that i was using a "very old" version of redux-saga (0.10.4). When upgrading to the current version of 0.16.0 it works as intended and the error is no longer present.